# how to store a list of objects in session

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration

i want to store a list of objects in session

```
List<ContentQueueLog> inactiveContent = GetInActiveContent(this.userID, this.visitorID);
```

when i store this list in sesssion it is stored but while trhying to get it
its null

i am storing sessions in sql 
someone hinted me about serialization 
but i cudnt get it
need some explaination

Comment: How do you know that the list is stored in session if you are getting null? As for the SQL storage you need to decorate the `ContentQueueLog` class with the `[Serializable]` attribute.

Comment: @darin: where i set the session i was getting the value properly
but on other pages it was null
but adding the attribute [serializable] solved the issue
thanx Darin
but i cudnot get the science behind this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an out-of-process storage for the session such as SQL Server or state process you need to decorate the objects that you intend to store in session with the [`[Serializable]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) attribute because they need to be transmitted over the wire and saved as a binary representation. Later when you try to read them from the session ASP.NET will fetch this binary representation over the wire and deserialize them back to the original object.